# CSS paddings are aplied only after hover

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm building React app and for last few hours I've been struggling with weird issue. CSS paddings on td are applied after `hover` on that cell but they should be applied before.

I've tried to split paddings from `padding: ...` to `padding-right/left...` and many other things. In html template it works fine but in react it's acting weird.

CSS for padding looks like this

```css
.itemsList .contentList .itemsLisTtabs  table td {
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

CSS for hover:

```css
.itemsList.itemsList_rollingStock table td:nth-child(3) span:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

You can see that behavior in this 
[gif.](https://gifyu.com/image/h3Mj)

I can see paddings applied in developer tools but visually it is not. If i unclick and click that padding in developer tools it also fixes. If anyone could help I'd be really happy.

Comment: And what's your relevant - [mcve] - HTML?

Comment: This seems very odd. Its possible its a browser issue and you've caught a bug but more likely there is something that is adding padding on hover. Can you inspect and toggle hover on all the elements it could be and see if you can replicate the behavior? Its hard to help debug too much without a working code example but the snippets you've linked all look fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same selector for your non-hovered state as for the hovered state, except for the `:hover` part and up to the `td`, i.e.

```
.itemsList.itemsList_rollingStock table td {
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```